# Привет, можете помочь, как в питоне можно записать код, чтобы решить выражение: R = sqrt(98 + sqrt(95 + sqrt(92 + ... + sqrt(5 + sqrt(2)))))

Tags: python

R = sqrt(98 + sqrt(95 + sqrt(92 + ... + sqrt(5 + sqrt(2)))))

Comment: проще всего использовать цикл for c соответствующим range

Comment: Используйте рекурсию :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы далеки от программирования, то вот вам решение:

```
import math

def Calc(val):
    if (val == 2): return math.sqrt(2)
    res = math.sqrt(val + Calc(val - 3))
    return res

print (Calc(98))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def recursive(n, step=1, debug=False):
    if n <= step:
        return n**.5
    if debug:
        print(f'{n}**.5 + recursive(n={n-step}, step={step}))**.5', )
    return (n + recursive(n=n-step, step=step))**.5
```

---

```
from functools import reduce

def iterative(n, step=1):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: (x**.5 + y), range(2, n+step, step))**.5
```

---

результат:

```
In [246]: recursive(98, 3)
Out[246]: 10.40440565283661

In [247]: iterative(98, 3)
Out[247]: 10.40440565283661
```